# segmentation fault by realloc 2 dim array but right output?

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault, malloc, realloc

Hi there I have a problem because I do not understand why my C programm has an segmentation fault. My programm creats a 2 dim int array and every line is going to be malloced by the fixed size of 5 and random numbers are in each line. But the user can choose if he wants to put more than 5 int in one line if he wants to i realloc my line. Every line lenght is stored in the array size. So the output is fine: for Example
1,6,3,4
8,6,5,3,2,1,6,8,9
1,4
8,9,6,4,2

But after the output my programm ends with an segmentation fault but why?? is my mistake somewhere in the free function or in my output?? Thanks for any Answer and sry for my bad english :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void flushi(){// to flush the buffer 
char buff = ' ';
    while ((buff = getchar()) != '\n' &&buff !=EOF);
    return;
}
void freeall(int **arr,int zeilen){
    for (int i = 0; i < zeilen; i++) { 
        free(arr[i]);
    }
    free(arr);
}

int main(){
    int zeilen=4;
    int d,j;
    srand(time(0));
    int spalten=5;
    int size[spalten];
    int **arr=malloc(sizeof(int*)*4);
    for(int i=0;i<zeilen;i++){
        arr[i]=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int*)*spalten);// malloc first line
        j=0;
        while(1){
            printf("Wollen sie noch eine Zahl eingeben\n");
            printf("1...Ja      0...Nein\n");
            scanf("%i",&d);
            flushi();
            if(d==1){
                if(j>=spalten){// if user want more than 5 int in one line
                    spalten++;
                    arr[i]=realloc(arr[i],sizeof(int)*spalten);// realloc line
                }
                arr[i][j]= (rand()%10)+1;
                j++;
                printf("Sie haben schon %i Zahlen eingegeben\n",j);
            }
            else{
                break;
            }
        }
        size[i]=j;
    }
    printf("Your Numbers\n");
    for (int h=0;h<spalten;h++){
        printf("\n");
        for (int g=0;g<size[h];g++){
            printf("%i ",arr[h][g]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    freeall(arr,zeilen);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: printf("Wollen sie noch eine Zahl eingeben\n");        Is printf("Do you want to add a number\n")

Comment: printf("Sie haben schon %i Zahlen eingegeben\n",j); Its a information how many number you have put in one line

Comment: logically, `arr[i]=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int*)*spalten);` should be `arr[i]=malloc(sizeof(int)*spalten);`

Comment: but then this warning comes: p.c:25:9: error: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Werror]
   arr[i]=(int)malloc(sizeof(int)*spalten);// malloc first line

Comment: ok sorry ;) i have done your correction

Comment: i never said to cast the result of `malloc()` to  `(int)`,

Comment: but my problem is still there the sementation fault after the output

Comment: sorry i misunderstand your correction at first :) arr[i]=malloc(sizeof(int)*spalten); Now i have this but the segmentation fault is still there ? do i have another mistake?

Comment: don't thank yet. let us debug the issue first. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, the problem is in

```
for (int h=0;h<spalten;h++)
```

in your code, you've allocated memory for only 4 `int *` [`int **arr=malloc(sizeof(int*)*4);`] but later in your code, you've incremented `spalten` and later using the incremented value in printing.

There you're accessing out-of-bound memory producing undefined behaviour.

you should change your print loop to

```
for (int h=0;h<4;h++)
```

<sup>P.S - Sorry, i'm also not a native English speaker</sup>

Answer (score 0):

```
There are several problems.
I have added comments about some of the problems to the original code

Please comment your code, for two major reasons
1) so in a few months you do not have to reverse engineer the code
2) so I do not have to reverse engineer your code 
   so that I can helpfully comment on what went wrong in the code

Note: getchar returns a int value, not a char value
      and '\n' on certain OSs is 2 characters
      and EOF is -1, not a char

The second code group is a suggested fix
In the second code group, there are certain improvements

that could be easily made,  
For instance, eliminate the spalen variable
allocate for the rows only once via:

if user enters 0,  
then use the default length, 
otherwise the user entered length


----Original code group with some comments----

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void flushi()
{// to flush the buffer 
    char buff = ' ';

    while ((buff = getchar()) != '\n' &&buff !=EOF);
} // end function: flushi


void freeall(int **arr,int zeilen)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < zeilen; i++)
    { 
        free(arr[i]);
    }
    free(arr);
} // end function: freeall


int main()
{
    int zeilen=4;
    int d,j;

    srand(time(0)); // should be srand( time( NULL ) );

    int spalten=5;
    int size[spalten];

    int **arr=malloc(sizeof(int*)*4); // allocate room for 4 pointers to integers
       // should always test returned value from malloc to assure operation successful

    for(int i=0;i<zeilen;i++) // foreach of the 4 pointers to integers
    {
        arr[i]=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int*)*spalten);// ERROR: allocate room for 5 pointers to intege
             // should be: arr[i] = malloc( sizeof(int)*spalten); // allocate room for 5 integers
             // should always test returned value from malloc to assure operation successful

        j=0;

        while(1)
        {
            printf("Wollen sie noch eine Zahl eingeben\n");
            printf("1...Ja      0...Nein\n");
            scanf("%i",&d);
                // should always test returned value from scanf to assure operation successful

            flushi();

            if(d==1) // 
            {
                if(j>=spalten)
                {// if user want more than 5 int in one line
                    spalten++;
                    arr[i]=realloc(arr[i],sizeof(int)*spalten);// realloc line
                        // always test returned value from realloc before
                        // 1) to assure operation was successful
                        // 2) before using the new pointer
                        //    otherwise old allocation lost, resulting in a memory leak
                } // end if

                arr[i][j]= (rand()%10)+1;
                j++;
                printf("Sie haben schon %i Zahlen eingegeben\n",j);
            }

            else
            { // else, user did not enter 1 ????
                break;
            } // end if
        } // end while

        size[i]=j; // remember/ save meaningless number
    } // end for

    printf("Your Numbers\n");

    for (int h=0;h<spalten;h++) // foreach 0...4
    {
        printf("\n");

        for (int g=0;g<size[h];g++) // for each 0...meaningless value
        {
            printf("%i ",arr[h][g]);
        } // end if
    } // end for

    printf("\n");

    freeall(arr,zeilen);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
} // end function: main

----second code group which is a suggested fix----

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

void flushi()
{// to flush the buffer
    int buff;
    while ((buff = getchar()) != '\n' &&buff !=EOF);
} // end function: flushi


void freeall(int **arr,int rowCount)
{
    // free each row
    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
    {
        free(arr[i]); // note: ok to call free() with null pointer
    }

    // free the array
    free(arr);
} // end function: freeall


#define MAX_ROWS (4)
#define DEFAULT_ROW_LEN (5)

// notice the removal of unneeded variables

// notice that most features are implemented 
// in separate code blocks

int main()
{
    int rowLength;  // new length (of integers) for each row
    int i, j;       // loop index/counters

    int spalten=DEFAULT_ROW_LEN;  // default length (of integers) for each row

    int size[MAX_ROWS] = {0};  // save area for final length of each row

    int **arr = NULL;
    if( NULL == (arr=malloc(sizeof(int*)*MAX_ROWS) ) ) // allocate room for MAX_ROWS pointers to integers
    { // then malloc failed
        perror( "malloc failed for number of rows" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, malloc successful

    // clear first memory allocation (int pointers) to NULLs
    memset( arr, 0x00, MAX_ROWS*sizeof(int*) );

    for(i=0; i<MAX_ROWS; i++) // foreach of the rows
    {
        if( NULL == (arr[i]=malloc(sizeof(int)*spalten) ) )
        { // then, malloc failed
            perror( "malloc failed for row" );
            freeall( arr, MAX_ROWS ); // cleanup
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        // implied else, malloc successful

        size[i] = spalten;

    } // end for each row

    srand( time( NULL ) );

    for( i=0; i<MAX_ROWS; i++) // foreach row
    {
        printf("Wollen sie noch eine Zahl eingeben\n");
        printf("1...Ja      0...Nein\n");

        if( 1 != scanf("%i",&rowLength) )
        { // then scanf failed
            perror( "scanf failed for row length" );
            freeall( arr, MAX_ROWS ); // cleanup
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        // implied else, scanf successful

        flushi();

        if( rowLength > 0) // 0 means no change and negative numbers are ignored
        { // then, user wants a different length for this row

            if(rowLength != spalten)
            {
                size[i] = rowLength;
                int * temp;

                // if user want other than 5 int in one row
                if( NULL == (temp = realloc(arr[i],sizeof(int)*rowLength) ) )
                { // then, realloc failed
                    perror( "realloc failed for row length change" );
                    freeall( arr, MAX_ROWS ); // cleanup
                    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
                }

                // implied else, realloc successful

                arr[i] = temp; // update the pointer in the array
            } // end if
        } // end if

        // fill in row of arr with random values
        for( j = 0; j<size[i]; j++ )
        {
            arr[i][j]= (rand()%10)+1;
        } // end if

        printf("Sie haben schon %i Zahlen eingegeben\n",j);
    } // end for

    printf("Your Numbers\n");


    for (int i=0;i<MAX_ROWS;i++) // foreach row
    {
        printf("\n");

        for (int j=0;j<size[i];j++)
        {
            printf("%i ",arr[i][j]);
        } // end if
    } // end for

    printf("\n");

    freeall(arr,MAX_ROWS); // cleanup

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
} // end function: main
```